# SQL Select Sets / Years 1-10 of Results

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, set

I always only need the most recent 10 years of data from the result set.  The years will always have multiple records, so I can not pull only the first 10 records.  How can I: SELECT Set 1, SELECT Set 2... through set 10 and only display those 10 years of data without pulling prior years?

```
Year    Quarter    Quarterly_yield
2012    1         8.41
2012    2        -0.71
2011    3         0.03
2011    4         3.43
2010    1         8.41
2010    2        -0.71
2009    3         0.03
2009    4         3.43
2008    1         8.41
2008    2        -0.71
2007    3         0.03
2007    4         3.43
2006    1         8.41
2006    2        -0.71
2005    3         0.03
2005    4         3.43
2004    1         8.41
2004    2        -0.71
2003    3         0.03
2003    4         3.43
2002    1         8.41
2002    2        -0.71
2001    3         0.03
2001    4         3.43
2000    1         8.41
2000    2        -0.71
```

Comment: What is the SQL query you are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this this way:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE year IN 
                     (SELECT year FROM table ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 10);
```

This query can explained like this:

1. Inner query - select last 10 years from `table`
2. Outer query - select all columns from `table` where year in inner query result

Comment: in the example, you can see it's not the last 10 years. It could be in a period of 20 years.

Comment: I was thinking about your query at first but then I realized that the question is "the 10 most recent years" and not "10 years ago"

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE year IN 
  (
   SELECT year
   FROM table
   ORDER BY Year DESC
   LIMIT 10
  )
```

This selects the 10 most recent years

```
SELECT year
FROM table
ORDER BY Year DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Then you select every records with those years

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from t 
where
(year>(select max(year) from t)-10)
order by year desc, quarter desc
```